# On The Use Of Unsanboxed Plugins In The Chrome Browser

Tags: google, chrome, flash

The following questions relate to unsandboxed plugins under Settings > Advanced > Content settings > Unsandboxed plugins.

The first thing I'd like to know is whether this setting is basically for Flash sites?

If I don't plan on using Flash would I be more secure if I just disabled sites from asking me if they can use a plugin to access my computer, or are there sites out there that do require plugins besides Flash?

Comment: Why not just disable unsandboxed plugins until you need them for a specific use case?

Comment: Because there are other people who use this computer that aren't as tech-savvy, who may be tricked into allowing a site to use a plugin to access this computer. If this setting is just for Flash, which almost by definition insecure, I'd rather just block plugins/Flash from running unsandboxed on those accounts, than running the risk.